# returning JSON response from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a new data registry using ajax, and then return it to the same page that created as JSON in rails 4.

This is my view

```
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#comments_form").bind('ajax:success', function(data) {
            alert($.parseJSON(data));
        });

        $("#comments_form").bind('ajax:error', function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        });
    });
</script>

<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build], remote:'true', format: :json, html: {id: :'comments_form'}) do |f| %>
     # form inputs go here
    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

And this is the controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create

    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @comment.as_json(only: [:commenter]) }
    end
  end
end
```

Everything seems to be working ok, the new record is created an the handler for ajax:success gets called, however parserJson fails with this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

If I set a breakpoint this is what I see inside 'data':

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKRHU.png

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - All handlers bound to jQuery events are always passed the event object as the first argument. Extra parameters denotes the parameters passed after the event argument. E.g. if the Extra parameters are listed as [xhr, settings], then to access them, you would define your handler with function(event, xhr, settings){}. See this article for a more in-depth explanation.

[Reference](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax)

Thus, you need to change your success handler as follows

```
$("#comments_form").bind('ajax:success', function(event, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

You would do the same for the error handler, passing `event` as the first parameter followed by the others as in your code. **Note** that you don't need to call `parseJSON` since data is already a JSON object.